# MySQL trouble getting FOREIGN KEY command to work

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

everything i find says something about the two items im trying to pull are different from their parent in some way but they arentthough

```js
CREATE TABLE Servers (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
paidRole BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ServerConfigurable (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
cmdPrefix VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT '!',
globalUngate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
globalAutoungate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
autoungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
embedHexcolor VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
webhookName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot',
webhookImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
footerMessage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot V1.0.1',
footerImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
FOREIGN KEY Servers REFERENCES Servers(serverId),
FOREIGN KEY Servers REFERENCES Servers(serverName)
);
```

and the error i get is

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Servers(serverId),
FOREIGN KEY serverName REFERENCES Servers(serverNa' at line 14

Comment: Syntax is `FOREIGN KEY column_from_current_table REFERENCES table_to_refer(column_from_the_foreign_table)` so your code should be like: `FOREIGN KEY serverId REFERENCES Servers(serverId)`

Comment: FOREIGN KEY (serverId)REFERENCES Servers(serverId),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every referencd column has to have an index

So you can do

```
CREATE TABLE Servers (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
paidRole BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
KEY(serverName)
);

CREATE TABLE ServerConfigurable (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
cmdPrefix VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT '!',
globalUngate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
globalAutoungate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
autoungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
embedHexcolor VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
webhookName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot',
webhookImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
footerMessage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot V1.0.1',
footerImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
FOREIGN KEY (serverId) REFERENCES Servers(serverId),
FOREIGN KEY (serverName) REFERENCES Servers(serverName)
);
```

Or Do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Servers (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
serverOwnerName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
paidRole BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
KEY(serverId,serverName)
);

CREATE TABLE ServerConfigurable (
serverId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
serverName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
cmdPrefix VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT '!',
globalUngate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
globalAutoungate BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
autoungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ungateWebhook VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
embedHexcolor VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
webhookName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot',
webhookImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
footerMessage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Gate Bot V1.0.1',
footerImage VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://imgur.com/a/eIULgfA',
FOREIGN KEY (serverId,serverName) REFERENCES Servers(serverId,serverName)
);
```